# Use jQuery to mirror height of a dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sidebar on my page that I want to always be 100% of the container size. Sadly, I can't tell the element to do this via CSS alone as the page has a variable height due to dynamic content.

Is it possible to use jQuery to find the height of the content container, and adjust the sidebar height to match it?

I found a few jQuery plugins that kind of do what I want, but feel they are over complicated (and I can't seem to get them to work anyway!).

Comment: try putting content and height into a single division with both height set to 100% and put the css at the bottom of your page...

Comment: @halocursed Why CSS at the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the id of your container is "container" and the id of your sidebar is "sidebar", you could try the following (untested!)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sidebar').height($('#container').height());
});
```

This should (on document load), resize the sidebar height to the same as the container height.

Comment: Note if you have anything that resizes the page (perhaps with `slideDown`) you will need to call this code again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to continue on from [Damovisa's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541866/use-jquery-to-mirror-height-of-a-dynamic-element/1541935#1541935)

```
$(document).resize(function(){
     $('#sidebar').height($('#container').height());
});
```

However, this could fire an awful lot if you resize the page a lot. You could try this

```
  $(document).resize(function(){         
        clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
        resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $('#sidebar').height($('#container').height());
        }, 100);
    });
```

In the second example, it will only resize 100 microseconds after resizing.

This is also assuming that `$(document).resize()` will be triggered when the page size changes. You could always wrap it in a function, and call it on completion of any `slideDown()` etc

Comment: Pretty good solution.  I guess the ideal solution really depends on what can change the size of the container.

Comment: Instead of listening to a document resize, why not bind to a window resize?